# Не получается подключиться к PostgreSQL в Go

Tags: windows, postgresql, golang

Не получается подключиться к PostgreSQL в Go. ОС Windows 10. PostgreSQL 14 установлен и все дополнительные компоненты.

```
package main
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

const (
    host     = "localhost"
    port     = 5432
    user     = "postgres"
    password = "1234"
    dbname   = "testbase"
)
 
func main() {
    psqlconn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", host, port, user, password, dbname)

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlconn)
    CheckError(err)
 
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    CheckError(err)
 
    fmt.Println("Connected!")
}

func CheckError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

При запуске кода выводится странная ошибка [image: фото с ошибкой]

Comment: нажмите [edit] и скопируйте текст ошибки текстом

Comment: из консоли получается средставми psql?

Answer (score 0):

Проверил у себя(заменил на свои DSN). Подключается, данные выгребает.
Вы пробовали подключиться к базе с другого компьютера?
Есть вариант добавить строки(если их нет) в pg_hba.conf
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5

Comment: строки в pg_hba.conf добавил, ошибка выводится такая же

Comment: А службу сервера pgslq перезапустили или компьютер перезагружали. Еще вариант везде проставить md5. И попробовать подключиться с другого компьютера через pgAdmin или dBeaver.